# Passing information from one website to another, securely

Tags: mysql, ssl

We are trying to integrate a VBulletin forum with a custom login scheme that is on another server.  We are thinking it would be a good idea to send the information through ssl but we have no idea on how to go about this.  What would be a good way to send information back and fourth between two webservers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon what you are trying to do. If you are just trying to use your custom login scheme, you may be able to create a connection to database and make the query to see if the authentication credentials are correct. If the information that you are trying to send is not stored in the database, then you may want to consider an https based [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) interface. This would allow you to make `GET` and `POST` requests of the other webserver. That server could return some XML with the data, which the client could process and act upon.